# Get specific value from an Action<Options>

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IBuilder builder, Action<Options> options) {

  return builder.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(??), x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(options));

}

public class SitemapOptions {
  public String Route { get; set; }
  public Double? CacheMaximumAge { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get `options.Route` value in `x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(??)`?

Comment: Is your options injected as `Action<Options> options` or `Action<SitemapOptions> options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your UseSitemap injects the `Action<SitemapOptions> options` instead of `Action<Options> options`. If that's true by using following code you can access the `Route` parameter.

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IBuilder builder, Action<Options> options) 
{
  SitemapOptions sitemapOptions = new SitemapOptions();
  options?.Invoke(sitemapOptions);
  // Now sitemapOptions.Route is populated.
  return builder.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(sitemapOptions.Route), x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(options));
}
```

The above code Invoke the action on parameter and populates it.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I am assuming that `Action<Options>` is meant to be `Action<SiteOptions>` and that `IBuilder` is supposed to be `IApplicationBuilder`)

If you're accepting an `Action<SiteOptions>` you'll need to create a new instance of `SiteOptions` and invoke the delegate upon it:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<SiteOptions> configure) { 
   // new instance
   var opts = new SiteOptions();

   // invoke delegate
   configure(opts);

   // opts is now populated 
   return builder.MapWhen(
     x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(opts.Route), 
     x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(opts)
   );  
}
```

Another (ha!) *option* is to restructure things a little and use the `IOptions` interface, configuring your options during `ConfigureServices`. This would allow you to either bind to a `ConfigurationSection`, accept a configuration delegate or both. You could then request the service from the builder's `ApplicationServices` while setting up the middleware:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   // use a delegate
   services.Configure<SiteOptions>(opts => opts.Route = "/route");
    // or use appsettings/config with a "SiteMap" section
   services.Configure<SiteOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("SiteMap"));
} 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
   // other stuff 
   app.UseSitemap();
} 

public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IApplicationBuilder builder) { 

   var opts = builder.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<SiteOptions>>().Value;
   
   return builder.MapWhen(
     x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(opts.Route), 
     x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(opts)
   );  
}
```

In my opinion, this approach gives you more flexibility with how you (and your consumers) configure the Middleware.

With both approaches, you can specify default values on your `SiteOptions` class in case the consumer doesn't configure them. For example the following will use a default route:

```
public class SitemapOptions {
  public String Route { get; set; } = "/sitemap"
  public Double? CacheMaximumAge { get; set; }
}
```